# Как разворачивать проект на Vagrant или Docker на продакшн после локальной разработки?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vagrant

Добрый день всем) Чтобы поднять на продакшн, нужно устанавливать Vagrant на продакшн ? Мне кажется это будет кушать лишние ресурсы сервера. Не нашел толковых статей в интернете на эту тему. Как развернуть Docker тоже интересно.

Comment: "как развернуть докер" - как обычно - установили докер, взяли докерфайл и запустили. Готово. Vagrant  на сервер обычно не ставят. Его суть - сделать серверное окружение на рабочем компе.

Comment: @KoVadim ну меня интересует как переносить проект с Vagranta на продакш, не вручную же всё делать, устанавливать. Также docker, нужно прям разворачивать его на сервере ?Не будет ли медленее работать, нежели просто установить всё

Comment: vagrant - (да и другие) - никто конечно руками не переносит. Пишут разнообразные скрипты деплоя. Докер конечно вносит накладные расходы, но обычно о них никто не переживает, так как плюсы, которые он приносит перевешивают эти накладные расходы. Даже большие компании пока предпочитают докупить сервачек, чем морочиться с прямым деплоем.

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, что лучше для Vagrant использовать, чтобы быстро разворачивать одинаковую конфигурацию как на сервере, так и у разработчиков ?

Comment: посмотреть версию софта сервера и выбрать подходящий "ящик" https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search

Comment: @KoVadim я читал нужно chef, ansible и т.д. Чтобы развертывать конфигурацию